# Theme Color Palette + Button not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I wanted to add a new colour to my buttons as states in the docs here: https://v4.mui.com/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors

But it seems that is failing and throwing me this error:

> Failed prop
> type: Invalid prop `color` of value `tertiary` supplied to
> `ForwardRef(Button)`, expected one of
> ["default","inherit","primary","secondary"].

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cxhi4?file=/demo.js

This may be a bug or bad documentation maybe?

Comment: The new color is available in the theme and you can reference the new color via theme object (e.g. in `makeStyles` or `withStyles`). 
But you cannot pass the newly added color in the `color` prop of the button component, as the error clearly mentioned the allowed options `expected one of ["default","inherit","primary","secondary"]`.